# Heroku deployment not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-cli, heroku-api

I am new here and as well in heroku.

I have one Ruby on rails application and i am trying to deploy on heroku. While deploying on heroku it gives me error. I have tried many things but no get solution. Anyone can please help me out. Sorry if it is silly question.

When i deploy on heroku, first it do bundle install then it automatically call rake command. How i don't know.

```
remote: rake update_commercial_attr_into_retail_and_office
    remote:     environment
    remote: rake update_the_utilization_rate_to_key_metrics:data_for_utilization_rate
    remote:     environment
    remote: rake update_version
    remote:     environment
    remote: rake updating_default_category
    remote:     environment
    remote: rake user_monthly_finacial_summary:financial_summary
    remote:     environment
    remote: rake user_monthly_finacial_summary:weekly_financial_summary
    remote:     environment
    remote: rake variance_explanation_report:variance_exp_for_all_user
    remote:     environment
    remote: rake variance_explanation_report:variance_exp_for_property
    remote:     environment
    remote: rake yml_code_remove:restore_yml_title
    remote:     environment
    remote: invalid option: -P
    remote: Test::Unit automatic runner.
    remote: Usage: vendor/bundle/bin/rake [options] [-- untouched arguments]
    remote: 
    remote:     -r, --runner=RUNNER              Use the given RUNNER.
    remote:                                      (c[onsole], f[ox], g[tk], g[tk]2, t[k])
    remote:     -n, --name=NAME                  Runs tests matching NAME.
    remote:                                      (patterns may be used).
    remote:     -t, --testcase=TESTCASE          Runs tests in TestCases matching TESTCASE.
    remote:                                      (patterns may be used).
    remote:     -I, --load-path=DIR[:DIR...]     Appends directory list to $LOAD_PATH.
    remote:     -v, --verbose=[LEVEL]            Set the output level (default is verbose).
    remote:                                      (s[ilent], p[rogress], n[ormal], v[erbose])
    remote:         --                           Stop processing options so that the
    remote:                                      remaining options will be passed to the
    remote:                                      test.
    remote:     -h, --help                       Display this help.
    remote: 
    remote: Deprecated options:
    remote:         --console                    Console runner (use --runner).
    remote:         --gtk                        GTK runner (use --runner).
    remote:         --fox                        Fox runner (use --runner).
    remote: 
    remote: /tmp/build_949c75f584a702ff1ad859dae4780088/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/test-unit-1.2.3/lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:94:in `rescue in process_args': $! is a read-only variable (NameError)
    remote:     from /tmp/build_949c75f584a702ff1ad859dae4780088/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/test-unit-1.2.3/lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:89:in `process_args'
    remote:     from /tmp/build_949c75f584a702ff1ad859dae4780088/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/test-unit-1.2.3/lib/test/unit/autorunner.rb:11:in `run'
    remote:     from /tmp/build_949c75f584a702ff1ad859dae4780088/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/test-unit-1.2.3/lib/test/unit.rb:278:in `block in <top (required)>'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:756:in `rake'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:132:in `log'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:777:in `allow_git'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:103:in `block in compile'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:92:in `compile'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:57:in `block in compile'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:55:in `compile'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:49:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:45:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:132:in `log'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
    remote:     from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote: 
    remote: !   Push rejected to amptechnologies-theamp2.
    remote:
```

This is my gem file.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.2'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
gem 'quickbooks-ruby','0.4.3'
gem 'acts_as_tree','2.4.0'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
gem 'capistrano', '2.5.19'
gem 'capistrano-ext', '1.2.1'
gem 'rvm-capistrano',  require: false
gem 'houston'
gem 'geocoder', '1.2.14'
gem 'dalli'
gem "rmagick", :platforms=>:ruby
gem "rscribd"
gem "rubyzip", '1.1.7',:require => 'zip'
gem "nokogiri", '1.6.7.1'
gem "spreadsheet"
gem "will_paginate" , "3.1.0"
gem "mysql2", '0.4.2', :platforms=>:ruby
gem "newrelic_rpm"
gem "libxml-ruby", :platforms=>:ruby
gem 'fog'
gem 'nas-yahoo_stock'
gem 'jruby-openssl' , :platforms => :jruby
gem 'bouncy-castle-java',"1.5.0146.1" , :platforms => :jruby
gem 'resque', '1.23.1'
gem 'resque-scheduler','1.9.9'
gem 'test-unit', '1.2.3'
gem 'rufus-scheduler', '~> 2.0.9'
gem 'tree_hierarchy', '2.1.1'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.9'
gem 'json'
gem 'tilt', '1.4.1'
gem 'httparty', '0.11.0'
gem 'magic_encoding'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'
gem "galetahub-simple_captcha"
gem "nested_form", :git => "git://github.com/madebydna/nested_form.git", :platforms => :ruby
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'rsolr', :require => 'rsolr'
gem 'rest-client', '1.6.7', :require => 'rest-client'
gem 'fancybox-rails'
gem 'money', '6.6.1'
gem 'fastercsv', '1.5.5'
gem 'american_date', '1.1.0'
gem 'time_diff'
gem "roo", "2.3.0"
gem 'roo-xls'
gem 'oj'
gem 'devise'
gem 'public_activity'
gem 'finance', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'byebug'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
gem 'twitter'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'jvectormap-rails', '~> 1.0.0'
gem "paranoia", "~> 2.0"
gem 'ratyrate'
gem 'zip-zip'
gem 'axlsx', '2.1.0.pre'
gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg", "~> 1.2.0"
gem 'combine_pdf'
#### Upgraded plugin To Gem ####
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'sidekiq', '4.2.7'
gem 'sidekiq-failures','0.4.5'
gem 'sinatra', :require => nil
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'ckeditor_rails'
gem 'wicked_pdf', github: 'mileszs/wicked_pdf'#em 'lazyload-rails'
gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"
gem 'imgkit'
gem 'wkhtmltoimage-binary'
gem 'fusioncharts-rails'
gem 'groupdate'
gem "omnicontacts"
gem 'xirr'

#### Upgraded plugin To Gem ####

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'capybara', "1.1.2"
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'rails-erd'
  gem "rails_best_practices"
  gem 'rails-dev-boost'
  gem 'rb-inotify', '>= 0.8.8'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'forecast_io'
gem 'puma'
gem 'actioncable', github: 'rails/actioncable', ref: '6143352f8ffba303f0c7644be7573f6725554cb3'
gem 'link_thumbnailer'
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.9', require: 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
gem 'ruby_outlook'
```

Please anyone help of my stuff. Thank you.

Comment: Show the Gemfile please.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You can check gemfile. I have updated in my issue.

Comment: Move `gem 'test-unit', '1.2.3'` to the :test group, also why you need both 'test-unit' and `rspec`?, Move capistrano to the development group. Keep your Gemfile clean.

Answer (score 0):

I can show you path

1- before deploy to production environment i would suggest you to run you application locally in production environment by running command

```
rails s -e production
```

this will make sure that if any requreiments related to production env is left or not. for example- it `should have secret_key , assets_precompile: true` ..etc. or if you are using devise then you would need to setup its key for production and some more thing depends on your gem specifications..

2 - update your heroku_cli to latest version.

3- follow up this [tutorial](https://guides.railsapps.org/rails-deploy-to-heroku.html) for heroku deployment